# Excel: Drop Down Computable Calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For my abilities in Excel I believe that has too many facets and I am certain using V/HLookup individually will not achieve the objective.

I have a list of products on Sheet 1, on Sheet 2 I need to make a a simple calculator selecting from the products list.

The products list is one large table with the product part, price, rrp etc which can be filtered by part name.

On Sheet 2 I would like to try the following:

| Part Type | Part Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wheels | (Column B - Row 2) | row |
| Exhaust | row | row |
| Part 3 | row | row |
| Part 4 | row | row |

I need to make the 'Column B- Row 2' a drop down list of all the parts corresponding to the 'Part Type 'Wheels''.

Comment: Try using index() with match() to pull the relevant items into a list that is referenced by the drop down.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? `Excel365` has some dynamic behavior which can make your task easy.

Comment: I am using O365 Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Excel 365, this can be done using the FILTER and XLOOKUP FUNCTION

Sheet 1 sample Data

[image: Product list]

Result in Sheet 2

[image: Result]

Formula in cell E3

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A3,""))
```

Data validation in Cell B3 (dont forget the **#** symbol in formula)

[image: Data Validation]

Formula in Cell C3 for price

```
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3,Sheet1!A:A&Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!C:C,"Not Found")
```

Comment: This is somewhat useful but the bit that confuses me here is the use of transpose, why is that required?

Comment: if you don't use transpose, the FILTER function will spill the filtered data to the cell below, and since we already have data in the next cell below, it will give error

Comment: I've been trying to use your technique for a short while with no joy. For the sake of clarity using my actual data, these are my cell numbers:

Comment: can you clarify, what problems are you facing, are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Finally got it to function, thanks for the educational direction.